# how to reload the html DOM with selenium so that the new commands will locate the new nodes?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

So I'm doing some tests one a page that changes it's html tree after clicking certain buttons and links. but the webdriver keeps searching only through the old html DOM.

So how can I target the newly added webelements? or how can I make the webdriver load the new Html DOM so that it target the new elements? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WebDriver` does poll the DOM automatically.

Just use implicit or explicit wait before interaction with recently added web elements:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits